# Exception: DataAnalysis.Reference+<>c__DisplayClass4 is not serializable

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, delegates

I am trying to serialize objects of class `Reference` at the end of my program. A serialization exception is thrown, which complains that "DataAnalysis.Reference+<>c__DisplayClass4" is not marked as serializable.

Initially I had the two delegates without the `Serializable` attribute, so I gave it a try, but it didn't change anything. The classes `Cacheable` and `Operation` are already marked as `Serializable` - and in fact the serialization of the both of them worked perfectly fine before I introduced the `Reference` class.

I don't even know what c__DisplayClass4 means. So I am sorry, but I don't know what other parts of my 1 megabytes+ source code to post here to help you solve the problem, because in the end I would be posting everything.

As I said, everything worked fine before introducing the `Reference` class. So I am hoping the problem is somehow localized to it.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DataAnalysis
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of Reference.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public class Reference
    {
        [Serializable]
        public delegate void ReferenceSetter(Operation op, Cacheable c);

        [Serializable]
        public delegate Cacheable ReferenceGetter(Operation op);

        readonly ReferenceGetter refGetter;
        readonly ReferenceSetter refSetter;

        public Reference(ReferenceGetter getter, ReferenceSetter setter)
        {
            refGetter = getter;
            refSetter = setter;
        }

        public Reference(FieldInfo operationField)
        {
            refGetter = (op => (Cacheable)operationField.GetValue(op));
            refSetter = ((op, value) => operationField.SetValue(op, value));
        }

        public Cacheable this[Operation op]
        {
            get {return refGetter(op);}
            set {refSetter(op, value);}
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: I have chosen taffer's first solution (avoid using the FieldInfo inside a delegate):**

```
public class Reference
{
    public delegate void ReferenceSetter(Operation op, Cacheable c);
    public delegate Cacheable ReferenceGetter(Operation op);

    readonly FieldInfo opField;
    readonly ReferenceGetter refGetter;
    readonly ReferenceSetter refSetter;

    public Reference(ReferenceGetter getter, ReferenceSetter setter)
    {
        refGetter = getter;
        refSetter = setter;
    }

    public Reference(FieldInfo operationField)
    {
        opField = operationField;
    }

    public Cacheable this[Operation op]
    {
        get 
        {
            if (opField != null) return (Cacheable)opField.GetValue(op);
            else return refGetter(op);
        }
        set 
        {
            if (opField != null) opField.SetValue(op, value);
            else refSetter(op, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Not polished yet, I will probably finally use an abstract `Reference` class with two implementations. But the principle becomes clear.

Comment: You are trying to serialize delegates, those are references to methods and not are best suited for serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because of the way you initialize your fields in the second constructor:

```
public Reference(FieldInfo operationField)
{
    // operationField is captured in the lambda below, which causes to generate an inner class
    // where operationField will be a field so can be accessed by the method of the lambda body
    refGetter = (op => (Cacheable)operationField.GetValue(op));
    refSetter = ((op, value) => operationField.SetValue(op, value));
}
```

**Solution 1**:

Do not capture locals and parameters of the enclosing method in the lambda. The field should rather be a parameter of the delegate.

**Solution2**:

Implement `ISerializable` and provide a custom serialization:

```
void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("getter", refGetter);
    info.AddValue("setter", refSetter);
}

// the special constructor needed for deserialization
private Reference(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    refGetter = (ReferenceGetter)info.GetValue("getter", typeof(ReferenceGetter));
    refSetter = (ReferenceSetter)info.GetValue("setter", typeof(ReferenceSetter));
}
```

Please note that deserializing delegates of non-static methods can be problematic. Maybe you should check the `Delegate.Method` property in `GetObjectData` and throw an exception if the setter or getter is an instance method.

Comment: I have chosen to implement the first solution (see my edit in the question). However it is completely unclear to me why the FieldInfo is so problematic when being used inside a delegate. Do you have a link that explains this a little more in depth?

Comment: It's not specific to `FieldInfo`. Lambdas are generated methods after all and if you use variables in them, which are from an outer scope they must be exposed for them somehow. The solution of the C# compiler for this was to generate fields for them in a hidden class and the lambda body accesses these captured locals via these fields. There is a good explanation here: https://medium.com/@Coder_HarryLee/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6 - though the article focuses to a side effect of this technique.

Comment: I am trying to recapitulate what I think I have understood: the only problem is, that this hidden class is generated automatically, which is why I don't have a chance to declare it with the Serializable attribute, right? It is not because I am capturing a local variable that is somehow out of scope during (de)serialization, right? Your recommendation of not capturing locals is only because then this hidden class will not be generated automatically, right?